# Web Scraping another website with specific class name in PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://haisha-yoyaku.jp/bun2sdental/list/?page=2');

    echo $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;
    $list = $html->find('div[class="list_search_casette_wrap"]',0);
    $list_array = $list->find('a');

    for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($list_array); $i++ ){
        echo $list_array[$i];
        echo "<br>";
    }

?>
```

I have this code that scrapes all links inside a div, but I want to specify the url since multiple  links are present inside `list_search_casette_wrap` div using a specific class name. how can I achieve that?

the `simple_html_dom.php` is a library I've found online. here is the link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Blitzkriegfest, have you tried using a foreach? E.X: `Foreach ( $html->find('div[class="list_search_cassette_wrap distinct-class-here"]') as $item ) { echo $item; }`

Comment: hello @PeriklisKakarakidis, if I put the distinct class there, it will be part of the div class. I want to get the url of the a with a specific class name inside that div.

Comment: Ok then use on the line of the list you are storring to the `$list_array` variable for example: `$list_array = $list->find('a[class="Class-Here"]');`

Comment: if you give simple data what you have and what you want its will be better

Comment: You could also change your selector to `div[class="list_search_casette_wrap"] a` and then loop on the found links.